# Apply elevation to TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a searchbar with similar styling to the Toolbar in the Google Photos app - that is, rounded with a drop shadow.

We're using a TextInputLayout from the Material library as the sole child of a fragment (which gets inflated at the top of parent fragments).

Below is what I have at the moment (I have a drawable available to use as the background once I can get the elevation to shop up, I've omitted that for clarity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.SearchFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchTextInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:paddingStart="24dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:elevation="20dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
                    android:hint="Search" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<!--android:background="@drawable/searchbar_rounded"-->
```

Am I missing something obvious here, or is this a limitation of the TextInputLayout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put textView inside cardView and it will make shadow for sure
Example of the cardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
```

Comment: Works great - just a heads up to anyone who stumbles upon this thread: if you're using AndroidX in your project use ```implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'``` in Gradle and ```androidx.cardview.widget.CardView``` in the XML

Comment: This answer is wrong, wrapping the layout in a CardView will break the appearance of error messages

Comment: @JohnvandenBerg if you did it wrong way yes it will brake. It you made CardView as container in won't. So make sure you implement it right way